# window.open works on localhost but not on web server

Tags: javascript

I have a line of code that is suppose to redirect the user to a website. When I run the code on my localhost it works, however when I upload it to my web server(000webhost) it does not redirect you. Here is the code: `window.open("https://www.w3schools.com");`
I have tried to clear my cache and try a different browser but it still does not work.

Here is the full code

```
    function Callback() {

  //Regex that only reads letters
  let regexCheck = /^[A-Za-z]+$/

  //Get the DOM elements
  let fname =  document.getElementById("firstName").value;
  let lname = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
  let midInit = document.getElementById("midInit").value;

  //Creates instance of date class
  var today = new Date();
  var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
  var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
  //today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
  document.getElementById('todayDate').value = today;

  //Checks that all fields are filled out
  if (fname && lname && midInit) {
    //Checks that only letters are used
    if (regexCheck.test(fname) && regexCheck.test(lname) && regexCheck.test(midInit)) {
      window.open("https://www.w3schools.com");
    } else {
      alert("Name can only be letters.");
    }
  } else {
    alert("Please answer all fields.");
  }
}
```

Comment: You usually can't call `window.open()` without some user interaction.  Show us your code.

Comment: i just added the full code to the post. Just so you are aware firstName, lastName, and midInit are coming from a html form.

Comment: This is not the full code.  What is calling `Callback`?

Comment: a onsubmit in a form is calling the function callback in a different html file

Comment: Could you set the value of `window.location.href` instead? Mind you, this will redirect the current page instead of opening a new tab/window

Comment: `window.location.href` does not work

Comment: How are you setting it? Just a note that it shouldn't be set the same way as `window.open` (which takes the value of the new location of an argument). `window.location.href` is just set directly. Try `window.location.href = "https://www.w3schools.com"` if you haven't already

Comment: yes i tried the exact thing you suggested

Comment: Are you seeing any warnings/errors in the console?

Comment: i do not see any errors

Comment: @henrykutrieb can u add the jsfiddle demonstrating the problem, because I tried to add your code in jsfiddle and found it O.K, If you want to see my fiddle you can find it here [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/keqar1v3/). In this fiddle your code is working fine.